# How to query a struct by multiple attributes in Solidity?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle

Suppose I have the following contract:

```
contract UserContract {
    struct User {
        address walletAddress;
        string organisation;
        string fName;
        string lName;
        string email;
        uint index;
    }
    mapping(address => User) private users;
    address[] private userIndex;
}
```

I know how to write a function that returns user information corresponding to a given `address`, but I'd also like to write a function that can grab user info by the `User`'s email address.

How does this work? Is my only option to create a separate mapping for this use-case that maps the `User` struct to a string? If so, does this mean the struct gets stored two times? Or does it only store references to that struct?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use for loop but it will take more processing , but for loop can be a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do a search by either address or email (ie, NOT a composite key), then yes, the simplest option is to use two different `mappings`. However, `struct` values are stored as copies (see [this](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#layout-of-state-variables-in-storage) for information on how mappings are stored).

To avoid extra storage for complex `structs`, store it in an array and use the index for the `mapping` values.

```
contract UserContract {
    struct User {
        address walletAddress;
        string organisation;
        string fName;
        string lName;
        string email;
        uint index;
    }
    User[] users;
    mapping(address => uint256) private addressMap;
    mapping(string => uint256) private emailMap; // Note this must be private if you’re going to use `string` as the key. Otherwise, use bytes32
    address[] private userIndex;
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you

Comment: Could you clarify what userIndex is for, Adam Kipnis? My understanding is that addressMap already provides mapping from user's walletAddress to index in array users.

Comment: Also why don't you make users - private? We would likely not want it to be modified directly from outside of this contract.